# Modifying private view appearance

Tags: ios, uitextview, iphone-privateapi, datadetectortypes

I would like to change the background color of a highlighted link in UITextView. After inspection I found about this: when a link is tapped a `UIHighlightView` is created and positioned inside the `UITextView` under the link. I would like to detect this view and change its color. Is this allowed by AppStore rules?

Answer (score 0):

It probably isn't allowed. You do have access to an alternative, though:

```
textView.linkTextAttributes = @{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]};
```

Comment: unfortunately this does work, maybe because I use an attributed string already as text. the `NSForeground...` attribute works, but not background

Comment: What if you assign a clear background to your whole string first? `[attribStr addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor clearColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, attribStr.length)];`

Comment: I even tried using it with standard NSString and link detection, I can't get the background attribute to work. Can you help me with this?